# Parsed Complex JSON Flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, parsing, dart

I am trying to parse this complex JSON data into a Flutter application. I am able to get the JSON data successfully, but not able to display the data in the application. See the code and JSON data below.
What I am doing wrong?

[JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF9L0.png)

```
{
"response": {
    "cars": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Ford Mustang GT",
                "class": "Muscle Car"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Dodge Challenger",
                "class": "Muscle Car"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Chevrolet Camaro",
                "class": "Muscle Car"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Pontiac Firebird",
                "class": "Muscle Car"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

}

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xkil.png)

```
class Cars {
  Cars({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.carClass,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String carClass;

  factory Cars.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cars(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        carClass: json["class"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "class": carClass,
      };
}
```

[API Service getting the JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFXEW.png)

```
class ApiService {
  Future<List<Cars>> getCars() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get('http://localhost:3000/response');

    var body;

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> carList = body['response'];
      print(body);
      List<Cars> res =
          carList.map((dynamic item) => Cars.fromJson(item)).toList();

      return res;
    }
  }
}
```

[Display Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ3lX.png)

Comment: What do you get when you run your code?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad When I run the code, there is no data in the screen. The circularprogressbar keep spining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can help in the construction of the classes with this application. (https://app.quicktype.io/)

These are the classes that you must use for the obtained object. Be sure to change the name of the classes that you think are relevant.

```
class Response {
    Response({
        this.response,
    });

    final ResponseClass response;

    factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Response(
        response: ResponseClass.fromJson(json["response"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "response": response.toJson(),
    };
}

class ResponseClass {
    ResponseClass({
        this.cars,
    });

    final List<List<Car>> cars;

    factory ResponseClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseClass(
        cars: List<List<Car>>.from(json["cars"].map((x) => List<Car>.from(x.map((x) => Car.fromJson(x))))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cars": List<dynamic>.from(cars.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x.toJson())))),
    };
}

class Car {
    Car({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.carClass,
    });

    final int id;
    final String name;
    final String carClass;

    factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Car(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        carClass: json["class"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "class": carClass,
    };
}
```

Finally, replace this line:

```
body = jsonDecode(response.body);
List<dynamic> carList = body['response'];
print(body);
List<Cars> res =
          carList.map((dynamic item) => Cars.fromJson(item)).toList();
```

with this:

```
return Response.fromJson(response.body);
```

and replace the data type that the function returns to Response.

Comment: Which line I should replace in this chunk of code? body = jsonDecode(response.body);
List<dynamic> carList = body['response'];
print(body);
List<Cars> res =
          carList.map((dynamic item) => Cars.fromJson(item)).toList();

Comment: @neuryzonso Everything you mentioned is replaced by the second code I put in. 
return Response.fromJson(response.body);

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow the [official](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) documentation for flutter Serializtion. It's good and also saves us from the hassle of creating the conversion HashMaps.